# CK Editor config.js changes doesn't work (basic version)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm having trouble setting up CKEditor. I managed to make it work, production-wise, but now I need to tweak some options like:

```
config.entities_latin = false;
```

(inside config.js), and it doesn't work, it still changes caracters like: šđžćčšđ to &Scaron etc.

I have tried the: `config.autoParagraph = false;` this doesn't work too.

However if I delete some elements from: config.toolbarGroups = [ ] (this works)..

Please notice that I have to use the basic version (for some reason, standard and full version doesn't work at all on server, only locally) :S

Anyone, help please...
This is entire config.js:

```
    /**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2014, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For the complete reference:
    config.contentsLanguage = 'hr';
    config.entities_latin = false;
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for a single toolbar row.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'others' }

    ];

    // The default plugins included in the basic setup define some buttons that
    // we don't want too have in a basic editor. We remove them here.
    config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Let's have it basic on dialogs as well.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which version you have. Try removing all entities. This works for me, my cke output is 100% XML compatible.

```
config.entities = false;
config.removePlugins = 'entities';
```

You can add `config.entities_greek = false;` or the latin one too but I don't really think it's necessary.